# Trabajar con un repositorio local en ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Tengo una instalación de **ubuntu server 18.04** y debo instalar un paquete mediante un *script*. El script usa un repositorio de la siguiente forma:

```
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] http://debian-repository.empresa.net/repositories/ bionic stable unstable"
```

Sin embargo, yo tengo este repositorio localmente copiado en el directorio:

```
/repo/repositories/
```

¿Cómo debo cambiar mi *script* para usar ese repositorio local a la hora de instalar el paquete?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes, pero si lo que quieres es instalar un paquete desde un repositorio en concreto, se haría así: sudo apt-get -t bionic install [paquete] si es que tu repositorio se llama bionic

Comment: El problema es que el server no tiene conexion a internet. el paquete que debo instalar se encuentra tambien en local, y se instala mediante un script .sh, pero busca algunas dependencias que se encuentran en ese repo. Lo que necesito es cambiar la direccion (http://debian...) a un path local de la maquina, o sea, /repo/repositories

Comment: Si tienes montado un repo local, se me ocurre que puedes usar el fichero /etc/hosts para indicar que vaya al local en lugar de al oficial. Pero como digo, no se muy bien que tienes entre manos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De la página del manual de [sources.list](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.es.html) obtenemos la siguiente información sobre las **URIs** que podemos utilizar para especificar la localización de los repositorios:

En tu caso la **URI** sería del tipo

> file:/repo/repositorios bionic stable unstable

Menciona también estas otras:

**cdrom** para indicar un repositorio en CD.

> cdrom:[elquesea]/ bionic stable

**http** la más habitual para indicar un servior web.

> http://dominio/repo/repositorios bionic stable unstable

O **ftp** entre otros más exóticos como rsh o ssh.

> ftp://dominio/repo/repositorios bionic stable unstable

Osea que puedes modificarlo tal que así:

```
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] file:/el/path/de/tu/repo/ bionic stable unstable"
```